# Updated Eclipse with the new SDK tools(rev 23) and ADT(23.0.0) I am unable to create New Activity of type "Navigation Drawer Activity"

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-adt

I updated my eclipse with latest android sdk and Adt tools. Now when I try to create a new Activity by choosing "Navigation Drawer Activity" Template, It does not create any thing. Even preview window does not show anything. Same behavior is observed when I choose templates like Tabbed Activity, Blank Activity, Blank Activity with Fragment .

Comment: Having the same issue. I think it's a bug in ADT 23.0.0

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72603 it's a bug in ADT 23